# How to change my TextView value by clicking ImageButton in ListView

Tags: android, listview, android-imagebutton

This is my listview, my problem is why I'm trying to click on my ImageButton(in listview) but the textview(in listview) never change the value that what I want. It's take my whole morning, can someone please help me, Thanks.

```
 public class ViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements Filterable {

        LayoutInflater mInflater;

        public ViewAdapter() {
            mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity());
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return pl.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

            if (convertView == null) {
                convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.listproduct, null);
            }
            final TextView ProductCode = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.productcode);
            ProductCode.setText("" + pl.get(position).getProductCode());
            final TextView Qty = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.qty);
            Qty.setText("" + pl.get(position).getQty());
            final TextView Description = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.description);
            Description.setText("" + pl.get(position).getProductName());
            final String p = Description.getText().toString();
            final TextView Price = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.price);
            Price.setText("" + pl.get(position).getProductPrice());
            final ImageButton minus = (ImageButton) convertView.findViewById(R.id.minus);

            minus.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                     Qty.setText("testing")// textview never change to "testing"
                }
            });
            notifyDataSetChanged();
            return convertView;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically you should use RecyclerView,but if you still want to use the listView, use the view-holder approach as in this link below:

[Optimize list view](https://dzone.com/articles/optimizing-your-listview)

And you should never ever call `notifyDataSetChanged()` in getView method as its called multiple time as your listview scrolls

Answer (score 0):

Please try your code with holder just like follows

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    ViewHolder holder;

    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_entry, null);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.nameTextView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.person_name);
        holder.surnameTextView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.person_surname);
        holder.personImageView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.person_image);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    }
    else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    Person person = getItem(position);

    holder.nameTextView.setText(person.getName());
    holder.surnameTextView.setText(person.getSurname());
    //holder.personImageView.setImageBitmap(person.getImage());

    return convertView;
}
```

Then click as follows

```
holder.personImageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                 holder.nameTextView.setText("testing")// textview never change to "testing"
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Use this code : 





     public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

                    if (convertView == null) {
                        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.listproduct, null);
                    }
                    final TextView ProductCode = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.productcode);
                    ProductCode.setText("" + pl.get(position).getProductCode());
                    final TextView Qty = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.qty);

                    final TextView Description = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.description);
                    Description.setText("" + pl.get(position).getProductName());
                    final String p = Description.getText().toString();
                    final TextView Price = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.price);
                    Price.setText("" + pl.get(position).getProductPrice());
                    ImageButton minus = (ImageButton) convertView.findViewById(R.id.minus);
                     minus.setTag(position);
                    minus.setOnClickListener(clickButton);

                    return convertView;
                }

          private View.OnClickListener clickButton = new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Object tag =v.getTag();
                   if(tag!=null)
                  {
                  int pos = (Integer)tag;
               Qty.setText(pl.get(position).getQty());
              notifyDataSetChanged();


        }
                }
            } ;
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as i understand from your question this cannot be done because once you populate the data in custom  *listView* you have recreate it or call the custom  *listView*    again with text display you want to change!